# number of reading text in web page with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

how to found how many times a news(for example)are read in website?

```
<p> <!-- my news--></p>
var counter=0;
windows.onload=function() {
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Look into Google Analytics: http://www.google.com/analytics/

Comment: To do this with JS you'd need to use AJAX to request a script that will keep the count somewhere else; you can't maintain the count in JS itself because it get runs in the browser of each user who views the site.  You need to have something somewhere else maintain this data.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a JavaScript variable to hold your counter. Each time your page loads this variable is reset to 0.

You need to store the information somewhere, such as a database or in a file on the server. You can't store information like this inside your code.

Look into MySQL databases and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Your own server's logs can tell you how many times a page has been loaded, and that's a far easier approach than using JavaScript.  If you absolutely have to use JavaScript, you'll need to use Ajax (or something) to communicate the result to the server.

Really, Google Analytics is the right tool for this job.